Using Gsheet formula..would it be possible to extract the 2nd to the last value based on 2 criteria
I have column A as dates and column B as names and column C as number..
I need to extract the dates from column A based on 2 criteria (lookup array at column B and C).  Here is the link for reference
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i4KOdIMTeQGS6sTm4nvrt7vM70u7OyQ0XRfeorn5Opc/edit?gid=0#gid=0
I tried to extract the last matching values using xmatch.. i am stuck on the 2nd to the last issue

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

CHOOSEROWS with FILTER to find second to last match
Formula:
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(A2:A24, B2:B24 = F4), (COUNTA(FILTER(A2:A24, B2:B24 = F4))-1))

This formula uses functions such as FILTER(to get values matching the name) and CHOOSEROWS to to get the desired outcome.
Sample Output

References: CHOOSEROWS, FILTER


You may try:
=chooserows(filter(A:A,B:B=F4,C:C=3),-2)


